# Context initialization failed due to org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, maven-3

I upgraded Spring from version 1.5.8 to version 4.2.3.RELEASE. Project compiles fine but when i start tomcat i get following error.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
02 Sep 2016 21:07:46,235  INFO ContextLoader:285 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
02 Sep 2016 21:07:46,264 ERROR ContextLoader:336 - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3116)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1825)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:360)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    ... 28 more
```

Below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.nationalpayment.cp20</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsrv</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wsrv Spring-WS Application</name>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <stylesheetfile>${basedir}/../../src/main/javadoc/javadoc.css</stylesheetfile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>2.5.1</version> -->
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                    <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <!-- <excludeFilterFile>${project.basedir}/conf/findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile> -->
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>

                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <!--<resource> <directory>src/main/resources</directory> <excludes> <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> 
                </excludes> <filtering>false</filtering> </resource> -->
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>2.5.1</version> -->
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <file>pom.xml</file>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>${current.build.version}</token>
                            <value>${replacer.current.build.version}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- put your configurations here -->
                <configuration>
                    <entries>
                        <entry>
                            <prefix>CPIIWSRV-svn</prefix>
                        </entry>
                    </entries>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.2</version> <configuration> <source>1.6</source> <verbose>true</verbose> 
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel> <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo> 
                <aspectLibraries> <aspectLibrary> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> </aspectLibrary> </aspectLibraries> 
                </configuration> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals> 
                </execution> </executions> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> 
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> <version>1.6.6</version> </dependency> 
                <dependency> <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId> 
                <version>1.6.6</version> </dependency> </dependencies> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>1.2</version> -->
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>eviware</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>src/test/soap-ui-tests/webservicetestsuite1.xml</projectFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>1.7</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.1.1</version> <executions> <execution> <phase>generate-sources</phase> 
                <goals> <goal>generate</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> <configuration> 
                <generatePackage>net.nationalpayment.cp20.ws.schema</generatePackage> <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/</schemaDirectory> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->

            <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>net.nationalpayment.cp20.ws.schema</generatePackage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/</schemaDirectory>
                    <!-- <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/kyc</generateDirectory> -->
                    <generateDirectory>src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.nationalpayment.cp20</groupId>
            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            <version>${current.build.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring-WS dependencies -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <!-- Database settings -->
        <dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory</dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>
        <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</hibernate.dialect>
        <jdbc.groupId>mysql</jdbc.groupId>
        <jdbc.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</jdbc.artifactId>
        <cxf.version>2.6.0</cxf.version>
        <jdbc.version>5.1.28</jdbc.version>
        <jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>


        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade starts -->

        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.ws.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
        <!-- <dao.framework>hibernate</dao.framework> <web.framework>spring</web.framework> 
            <commons.fileupload.version>1.2.1</commons.fileupload.version> <commons.io.version>1.3.2</commons.io.version> 
            <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version> <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version> -->

        <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->



        <wsrv.timestamp>${timestamp}</wsrv.timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <current.build.version>versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT</current.build.version>

    </properties>

</project>
```

Below is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cftRest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cftAuth/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--PBE encription configs-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webPBEConfigServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
          org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEConfigServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webPBEConfigServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webPBEConfig.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>


     <filter>
        <filter-name>webPBEConfigFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEConfigFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webPBEConfigFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsd</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:${CONFIG_PATH}/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.I am using Eclipse and Maven3.

Comment: It seems like spring core dependency is missing, can you add the spring dependencies declared in the pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added pom.xml. Let me know what exactly is to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```